# Keep an updated list of php files in a database

Tags: php, oop

I need to have a page on my project poll the root directory and if it sees any new php files, it needs to add the filename to the database so I can deal with permissions.  That part seems to be working.

However, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to tell it to look at the root directory and get it to delete any pages from the db that aren't there anymore. Some of the problem is that a lot of the code at the bottom is not OOP and I'm returning my $dbpages as an object.  The $dbpages looks like this:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'id' => string '56' (length=2)
      public 'page' => string 'includeme.php' (length=13)
      public 'private' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[8]
      public 'id' => string '57' (length=2)
      public 'page' => string 'index.php' (length=9)
      public 'private' => string '0' (length=1)
```

While the $pages looks like this:

```
array (size=3)
  'includeme2.php' => string 'includeme2.php' (length=14)
  'includeme2_2.php' => string 'includeme2_2.php' (length=16)
  'index.php' => string 'index.php' (length=9)
```

Here's what I have so far...

```
$pages = getPageFiles();  //retreives php files in root
$dbpages = fetchAllPages(); //Retrieve list of pages in pages table of db
$count = 0;
$dbcount = count($dbpages); //Thought I could use this for something
$creations = array();
$deletions = array();

//Check if any pages exist which are not in DB
foreach ($pages as $page){
  if(!isset($dbpages->page)){
    $creations[] = $page;
  }
}
// dump($creations);

//Enter new pages in DB if found
if (count($creations) > 0) {
  createPages($creations)   ;
}

//EVERYTHING is working above this point

if (count($dbpages) > 0){
  //Check if DB contains pages that don't exist
  foreach ($dbpages as $page){
    if(!isset($page->page)){
      $deletions[] = $page->id;
    }
  }
}


// //Delete pages from DB if not found
if (count($deletions) > 0) {
deletePages($deletions);
 }

//Update DB pages
$dbpages = fetchAllPages();
```

For reference, my getPageFiles() function looks like this..

```
//Retrieve a list of all .php files in root files folder

function getPageFiles() {
    $directory = "../";
    $pages = glob($directory . "*.php");
    foreach ($pages as $page){
    $fixed = str_replace('../','',$page);
        $row[$fixed] = $fixed;
    }
    return $row;
}
```

And my fetchAllPages() looks like this:
//Fetch information on all pages

```
function fetchAllPages() {
  $db = DB::getInstance();
  $query = $db->query("SELECT id, page, private FROM pages");
  $pages = $query->results();
  return $pages;
}
if (isset($row)){
return ($row);
}
```

I'm somewhat new to OOP PHP, so any help would be great. This is part of an open source project that I'm giving away.

Comment: in `getPageFiles()`, why do you set your page name as the array key?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really sure, but that allowed me to just pop the actual file name into the database and it worked so I went with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem. A few of them actually:

- First problem is that you are not iterating correctly when checking if the pages exist in your current `$dbpages` array. You need another `foreach` inside your initial `foreach` to iterate through the `$dbpages` array.
- Another problem (which has to do more with efficiency) is that you are not leaving that iteration once your page is found, this makes your algorithim slower in performance. You need to use `break;`.
- Every iteration should give you want you want. If you iterate again to get your "deletions", than you are doing double the work. Use one iteration to obtain all you need.

what I would do is the following (Read the comments in the code):

```
$pages = getPageFiles();  //retreives php files in root
$dbpages = fetchAllPages(); //Retrieve list of pages in pages table of db
$creations = array();

/*
 * iterate through each page in directory, check each page to each page
 * found in DB, if the page exists in the DB, remove that page object
 * from the $dbpages array and set a bool flag to true. Once all pages in 
 * the DB are checked, check if the page was found, if not, add that to
 * the $creations array
 */
foreach ($pages as $page) { 
    $page_exists = false;
    foreach ($dbpages as $k => $dbpage) {
        if ($dbpage->page === $page) {
            unset($dbpages[$k]);
            $page_exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$page_exists) {
        $creations[] = $page;
    }
}

/*
 * Remaining DB pages (not found) are to be deleted. 
 * This function turns the remaining objects in the $dbpages
 * array into the $deletions array using the 'id' key. 
 */
$deletions = array_column(array_map(function ($o) {
    return (array)$o;
}, $dbpages), 'id');

//Enter new pages in DB if found
if (count($creations) > 0) {
    createPages($creations);
}

// //Delete pages from DB if not found
if (count($deletions) > 0) {
    deletePages($deletions);
}

//Update DB pages
$dbpages = fetchAllPages();
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had to edit my delete function a bit, but this is EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand your issue.

You say "EVERYTHING is working above this point".

In the code that follow you are walking thru all entries of the array *$dbpages*. These entries contain an object with the string attributes *id* and *page*. I do not see anything wrong how you are accessing these attributes.

So, if you wish to check, if the file according the attribute *page* exists you probably mean **file_exists()** instead of **isset()**. Which would give this:

```
if (count($dbpages) > 0){
    //Check if DB contains pages that don't exist
    foreach ($dbpages as $page){
//      if(!isset($page->page)){
        if (!file_exists($page->page)){
            $deletions[] = $page->id;
        }
    }
}
```